# ASP.NET textbox doesn't lose focus

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net web application. In my `.aspx` page I have a small jQuery dialog with two textboxes for which I am using a datepicker. How can I remove the focus of them when the dialog pops up. I've tried so many solutions posted on the internet and still they continue to be focused, therefore the datepicker shows and hides my whole dialog.

Here is the code I have for popping the dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var dialogOpts = {
            resizable: false,
            bgiframe: true,
            maxWidth: 330,
            maxHeight: 315,
            width: 330,
            height: 315,
            autoOpen: false
        };

        $('#borrow_dialog_form').dialog(dialogOpts).parent().appendTo($("#form1"));;
        $(function () {
            $("#borrow_dialog_form").dialog({
            });

            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                $("#borrow_dialog_form").dialog("open");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And here is the aspx:

```
<div id="borrow_dialog_form" title="Borrow" style="display: none;">
            <asp:Label CssClass="labelStyle" ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="From"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label CssClass="labelStyle" ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="To"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button Style="margin-left: 90px;" ID="borrow_item_button" runat="server" Text="Borrow item" OnClick="borrow_item_Click" />
    </div>
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try that?

```
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $("#borrow_dialog_form").dialog("open");
            $("#datepicker").blur();
            $("#datepicker2").blur();
            return false;
        });
```

or that?

```
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $("#borrow_dialog_form").dialog("open");
            $("#borrow_item_button").focus();
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Yes, but with no luck. It still opens the datepicker. However, the textbox is not focused. So, I guess this answers my question, but do you have any ideas on how to stop it from auto popping?

Comment: Okay, I found a solution to stop the auto open of the datepicker. I just had to add a `"TabIndex=-1"` and then the datepicker doesn't open automatically.